# Como hago una inserción de un arreglo en php a sql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un arreglo de usuarios

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user] => 'Luis'
       
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [user] => 'Ana'
       
    )
```

Así, pero mi duda es como podría insertar no por uno en la tabla. lo tengo en php y lo insertare a sql. Gracias por adelantado

Comment: ¿Usás **pdo** o **mysqli**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas te he enseño más o menos como deberías de hacerlo, en mi caso también te he añadido algo de código HTML para que puedas apreciar lo que pasa:

Una explicación simple del código seria que lo primero de todo usamos Php para generar el array, a continuación lo mostramos con html para poder ver que en una tabla(al menos para mí, la forma más simple de visualizar una array 2D)como esta ordenado y colocado.

Después lo que hacemos es introducir algo de información de la base de datos, como ip, usuario y contraseña y nombre de la tabla.

para finalizar, hacemos la primera parte de la query la cual sería generar el insert y recorrerlo tantas veces como numero de filas tenemos en el array, también para dar algo de seguridad lo que hacemos en vez de pasar directamente una Sting o un valor a la query con una función de PDO se lo pasamos como parámetro

```
      <?php 
    //generamos un array [0] => Array ( [user] => 'Luis')[1] => Array([user] => 'Ana')
    
    $usuarios = array(
    array(
            'nombre' => 'Juan',
            'apellido' => 'Perez',
            'edad' => '23',
            'email' => 'email        '
        ),
        array(
            'nombre' => 'Pedro',
            'apellido' => 'Perez',
            'edad' => '23',
            'email' => 'email '
        ),
        array(
            'nombre' => 'Maria',
            'apellido' => 'Perez',
            'edad' => '23',
            'email' => 'email'
        ),
        
    );
    //mostramos la array de usuarios en una tabla
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Nombre</th>';
    echo '<th>Apellido</th>';
    echo '<th>Edad</th>';
    echo '<th>Email</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$usuario['nombre'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$usuario['apellido'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$usuario['edad'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$usuario['email'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    
    //creamos una funcion para guardar los usuarios en una base de datos mysql con pdo en php
    function guardarUsuarios($usuarios){
//en este caso deberias de cambiar la informacion/configuracion para que se adaptara a tu base de datos mysql
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usuarios';
        $usuario = 'root';
        $contraseña = '';
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, edad, email) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :edad, :email)";
            $resultado = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $resultado->execute(array(
                ':nombre' => $usuario['nombre'],
                ':apellido' => $usuario['apellido'],
                ':edad' => $usuario['edad'],
                ':email' => $usuario['email']
            ));
        }
    }
    guardarUsuarios($usuarios);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que también cuentes con la opción de `mysqli`, suponiendo que tienes los datos de tu array controlados y no tendrás problemas de inyección de código, yo haría algo así:

```
<?php

$a = [
    ['user'=>'Luis',],
    ['user'=>'Ana',],
];

echo '<pre>'.print_r($a,true).'</pre>';

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario) VALUES ";
foreach($a as $ai)
    $sql.= "('".$ai['user']."'),";
$sql[-1]=";";

echo $sql;

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','');
$conn->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS __so;");
$conn->query("USE __so;");
$conn->query("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
      id_usuarios int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      usuario varchar(31)
      );
");
$conn->query($sql);
```